# Show that if complex matrices A and B are both hermitian, then ABA is also hermitian.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

i have never done a linear algebra proof, although i've written many others. please help me with this one....

"Show that if complex matrices A and B are both hermitian, then ABA is also hermitian."

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From the definition of the conjugate transpose of a matrix $A$, denoted by $A^{\dagger}$, you can show that if $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices, then $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}$.

Applying this property twice to $ABA$ yields: $(ABA)^{\dagger} = (BA)^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger} = ABA$, where the last equality follows from the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian matrices. Hence $ABA$ is also Hermitian.